# Can I get a link to install CF10 version?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml

Can anyone please point me to get an installable link for CF10? Actually I have to work with a CF10 website, so I need my developer version to be the exact version.

thanks in advance.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bwmlt4TArPS5SmswVTJ3WVpGU0k

Comment: You'll be able to find it in that drive.

Comment: http://www.cfmlrepo.com/

Comment: RRK    Is that a trusted source?

Comment: Who maintains that drive?

Comment: It's sad ADOBE doesn't keep these version although they are generating revenues from old versions.

Comment: @ADEv CFML Repo is a trusted community source. That drive is linked from the domain. How can Adobe generate revenue from a version they no longer sell? There's no new bug fixes, no security patches, no paid support. You'd have to upgrade for them to make any more money.

Comment: If you don't want to pay for a new ACF license (I don't blame you), might want to migrate over to Lucee. I've been using it exclusively for the past 5 years to build high traffic, scaleable apps.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the updates. That repo is very helpful

Comment: Personally, rather than install CF10, I'd opt for moving over to Lucee or upgrading. If I'm not mistaken, CF10 is incredibly vulnerable to Metasploit and script kiddies. The worries about security are probably more than it's worth.

Comment: And I really don't want to harp, but if you're stuck working with CF10, I'd try to push hard for an upgrade, and if that's not going to happen, I'd look very hard into how to lock the system down as much as possible. But also keep in mind that when there is a breach (assuming there hasn't already been an unnoticed one), the developers will be the ones blamed.

Comment: If I were Adobe, I'd be offering extreme discounts to at least CF2016 and assistance with the upgrade. CF10 is almost 20 years old and has several known vulnerabilities. But even still, every problem makes Adobe and CF look bad.

Comment: Plus, I'll mention that CF2016+ is _SO_ much better and easier to work with than CF10. :-)